# how to fix file_get_contents warning for twitter

Tags: php, json, twitter

I have a twitter feed for a website, and it has been working no problem last 5 mins, however all of a sudden it has stopped and throwing this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/xxx.json)

[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/fhlinux009/t/xxx.co.uk/user/htdocs/wp-content/themes/xxx/homepageTest.php on line 100
```

Replaced sensitive data with xxx.

The code for this is:

```
<?php
    $username='xxx'; // set user name
    $format='json'; // set format
    $tweet=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/
    user_timeline/{$username}.{$format}")); // get tweets 
    //and decode them into a variable
?>

<div id="sliderId">
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><?php echo $tweet[0]->text; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $tweet[1]->text; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $tweet[2]->text; ?></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have had to use this method to work with a slider. I am not sure why it stopped working.

**UPDATE: Is it possible to cache the result from file_get_contents for about 15 / 30 mins at a time if the request is exhausting the server?**

Comment: Double check the TWITTER API still supports this method your using.

Comment: Okay I will have a browse around for that. As I say it was working before though :/. Will take a look over their API

Comment: what type of url u want to hit?can you please tell me the url

Comment: Ensure that you're logged in before making the request

Comment: The URL your using does not wrap around to a new line, because in your source code here, and when I go to edit the page, i'm getting a space in the URL. This is causing the problem not returning the format for me. If you remove the wrap around, the url works when I'm using my screen name.

Comment: @MarkTomlin thanks for the reply, what is the wrap around sorry?

Comment: That's a good point @MarkBaker, but I was not logged in from my browser when I tested the url and it worked without error.

Comment: `/ user_timeline/` right there, it's showing a space in the url, is that in your source code as well? Because if it is that is what is causing the error for me, once I remove that space it works without problems.

Comment: @MarkTomlin Ahh no sorry :/ I newlined it in the source code to keep it in the window.

Comment: Oh, ok. Just a tip, leave the source code 'as is' even formatting should be the same to make sure that I have the exact same copy that you have. Try doing something like fetching a static json file from your own domain. If that works, them try fetching a static json file from someone else's domain.

Comment: I now think the issue is the requests have exhausted the server. Can I cache the result?

Comment: Yeah, you can cache the result and check it's create time, and if the creation time is greater then x seconds then go out and flush the cache and get the new version. It's pretty easy to set that up as long as you can write to your file system, or if you wanted to save it in a database, and save the json in one row and the request time in another row.

Answer (score 0):

1. check the url, ecxecute it manually in browser.
2. If url works in browser enable `allow_url_fopen` settings in php ini and restart the server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment I will do this, however I now think the issue is the requests have exhausted the server. Can I cache the result?